# How to correctly use as.POSIXct function inside a cat function

Tags: r, posixct

I would like to get a data format like  "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss timezone" for Sys.time() as part of the "cat" function. 
When I use the two functions by themselves there is no problem but when I use the conversion function inside the cat function I don't get the desired data format.
How can I solve this issue?

```
> cat("THE TIME NOW: ",as.POSIXct(Sys.time(), origin="1970-01-01"))
THE TIME NOW:  1468251677
> as.POSIXct(Sys.time(), origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2016-07-11 18:41:21 IDT"
```

Comment: `Sys.time()` returns a `POSIXt` object; you can just use `cat("Current time: ", strftime(Sys.time()))` if you want the default formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
cat("THE TIME NOW: ",as.character(as.POSIXct(Sys.time(), origin="1970-01-01"),usetz=T),sep="")
```

Output:

```
THE TIME NOW: 2016-07-11 16:55:15 BST
```

I just had to transform the output of the function as.POSIXct(Sys.time()) to character before using cat. The parameter usetz=T tells the as.character function that you want to keep the timezone.